# How to fix the problem of losing the uploaded files after new deploy of app DOKKU

Tags: docker, deployment, dokku

when i deploed my app for the first time with dokku, i used docker-option to host the uploadsIMG folder and every-thing works well, but when i update my app or restart it i lose all my images etc...
Thank you

I tried docker-option:

```
`dokku docker-options:add betrocapi run "-v /home/dokku/dataBetroc:/uploadsIMG"`
`dokku docker-options:add betrocapi deploy "-v /home/dokku/dataBetroc:/uploadsIMG"`
```

and when i run:

```
`dokku docker-options betrocapi`
```

it gives me:

```
`Build options:
    --link dokku.mysql.betrocsql:dokku-mysql-betrocsql
Deploy options:
    --link dokku.mysql.betrocsql:dokku-mysql-betrocsql
    --restart=on-failure:10
    -v /home/dokku/dataBetroc:/uploadsIMG
Run options:
    --link dokku.mysql.betrocsql:dokku-mysql-betrocsql
    -v /home/dokku/dataBetroc:/uploadsIMG
`
```

But when i change something in my i app and re-run `git push dokku master` i lose all my picture.
the logs of the new deployment is :

```
`       CHECKS file not found in container: Running simple container check...
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
-----> Default container check successful!
-----> Running post-deploy
-----> VHOST support disabled. Skipping domains setup
-----> Creating http nginx.conf
-----> Running nginx-pre-reload
       Reloading nginx
-----> Setting config vars
       DOKKU_APP_RESTORE:  1
-----> Found previous container(s) (d48be97bb479) named betrocapi.web.1
=====> Renaming container (d48be97bb479) betrocapi.web.1 to betrocapi.web.1.1547646932
=====> Renaming container (402abba16e28) fervent_hoover to betrocapi.web.1
-----> Shutting down old containers in 60 seconds
=====> d48be97bb47914c666fbcff5ede8fdf82093dad6c451e6bad2168b14f23ee41f
`
```

Ps: i try also : `dokku storage:mount ....` same result.

Any one can explain to me why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dokku have the same foundation as heroku.

The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral, so any changes to the filesystem will only live on the last active container of dokku that its running your application. So when you push your code basically dokku create a new container with files of your app and then replace it with the old one. Same thing happens when you shut down or restarted the app.

Using dokku storage it's possible to get it working just follow some steps of this guide [http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku~v0.7.2/advanced-usage/persistent-storage/](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku%7Ev0.7.2/advanced-usage/persistent-storage/) but notice that you will have to use the relative path ex. '/app/storage' in your app so the storage work. But for our experience after 1 year operating dokku apps on prod you can easily screw the files by mysterious reason of how dokku works.

If you really need to store data I recommend using a dedicated file storage service such as AWS S3 its super cheap. There are several gems that you can use to store that can easily help you to handle your files in S3 like papeclip, dragonfly, activestorage (if you are using Rails >= 5.2).